# system won't boot after running sudo apt purge

Tags: boot, apt, sudo, purge

I accidentally ran the command sudo apt remove ... whilst trying to uninstall some libraries and realized my mistake halfway through the removal process. I aborted the process midway and restarted, but now Ubuntu won't startup. I can log in normally, but I will just get stuck at the purple login screen, and I've tried to run recovery mode, but it just gets stuck not doing anything. What should my next steps be in order to make sure I don't lose any personal files?

Comment: Time for a full reinstall I would think.